# Wrong scaling on phone - Site with half width/height = full screen

Tags: cordova, screen, screen-resolution, phonegap-build, muse

So a little followup on my previous thread, but with quite new content.. And changes of the situation.

So I'm creating an Android app, writing in Adobe Muse *normally by notepad, but find Muse this time more easy* and configured all files as a Phone, with a resolution of 1280x720. And my test device is a HTC one X, with a screen resolution of 1280x720. Once all code is done, I compile it at Adobe Phonegap into an APK and install that one on my phone.

So in fact, what I write in muse (site @ 1280x720) should be 1:1 on my phones screen. However, that's not the case. In fact, it shows everything at 2times the size. I can scroll on my screen..

In fact, I've created a second version *with just an homepage and one image on it, using whole the canvas, but I've made this one exactly half the size of the original; thus a canvas of 360x760. Compiled and installed again, and indeed, guess what: No scrolling and the image takes up the full screen.

By other meanings: Somewhere on the road, my phone thinks it has a screen size of half (360x640) the dimensions it actually is (1280x720).

I did a quick test with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width,  initial-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5,  maximum-scale=0.5"/>
```

Hoping that it would somehow fit "half" to whole my screen, But without luck.

So guys: Here I am, all lost and got no clue anymore. Who can help me with a working HTML/CSS/JS configuration, or if the problem lies at the phone gap configuration, help me over there?

Click [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2bmi6u8qlbojdp/WrongScaledSite_apk.zip) to download the site files and the compiled APK to test for yourself. Note: If you install the APK on your phone (instead of an emulator) and you got a different screen size than 1280x720, of course scrolling occurs.

p.s. I've made a second test version, with just an home page at a resolution of 480x800 and with only an image on it, and tested it on the Samsung S3 mini too (with a screen res. of 480x800), and also the whole thing seems at 2x scaled.. I'm really lost.

p.p.s. Someone else said "Remember, you still got the statusbar". For those of you thinking the same: I've set it to full screen, hiding the statusbar and using the full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got a solution to (y)our problem:

- Open the YourApp.java located under "src/com.company.yourapp/YourApp.java"
- Place the following code below your loadUrl() call

> // Viewport Settings WebSettings settings = appView.getSettings();
>   settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
>   settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

- Open your index.html and (re)place the viewport metatag

> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5, width=device-width" />
> ```

Comment: You do know this is a WebApp, created with HTML, CSS & JS..? No java or loadUrl() things.

However, thanks for your input!

Comment: I do know this is a WebApp because I'm doing the same thing atm. You said "Android" and Phonegap which means that there has to be a java file.

1. Do you use the Android Developer Tools?
2. Is the phonegap project created via build.phonegap.com or CLI?

Comment: Hmz, Honestly, there is no java configuration file. However, this is from 3 months ago and havent used Phonegap since then. And as far as I know, i'm not using ADT and I've created it via build.phonegap.com. Thanks!

Comment: Basically every phonegap project that was done with phonegap build or CLI simultaneously create java files for the android version. Otherwise it wouldn't work. The html, javascript and css are encapsuled in a native wrapper. Android uses java for that, iOS uses C# and so on. If you still need to resolve this issue, I suggest you go to your project folder and search for any java files or more specific for "yourAppName.java".

Comment: When I tried this I get:

`: error: cannot find symbol
        settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        ^
  symbol:   variable settings
  location: class MainActivity
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
 FAILED
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.`